# How can i do this select in () / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two sources of data- One comes from the Database and one from a CSV File. The database comes just as a key.

From the CSV file contains more than one field

```
Id  firstname  lastname
1   first1     last1
2   first2     last2
3   first3     last3
```

I'm looking to do same with Pandas as what I can do with SQL:

```
select * from adr_tmp where id in(select id from xyz where key = ‘x’);
```

or

```
delete from adr_tmp where id in(select id from xyz where key = ‘x’);
```

After this I should have a new data frame with

```
Id  firstname  lastname
1   first1     last1
2   first2     last2
```

Comment: Have a read of the docs, after you've tried something or get confused update your question: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very hard, you can try:

```
adr_temp[adr_temp['id'].isin(list(xyz['id'][xyz['key'] == 'x']))]
```

This will return all fields from adr_temp, where 'id' is in the list of 'id''s from xyz, where 'key' = 'x'

For delete, you can simply select the complementary of the above:

```
adr_temp[~adr_temp['id'].isin(list(xyz['id'][xyz['key'] == 'x']))]
```

Comment: Please see the additional text

Comment: Please be more specific. Show a little extract of i5747 and topf tables (the field names and 2-3 rows of data). And what error is it throwing? or no error, just returning an empty dataframe? Last question, what version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: It was my fault. One was an int and the other one was string.